# Bootstrap sb-admin-2 theme not working properly in IE 11

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, frontend

I am new to bootstrap. I downloaded bootstrap `sb-admin-2` theme from the site

http://startbootstrap.com/template-overviews/sb-admin-2/

The template is working fine in Chrome but it is not working properly on `IE 11`. The styles don't get applied and graphs and charts are not visible. I can't upload the screenshot due to reputation constraint. Is there a need to make changes in some `CSS` files?

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Compared to IE, in my experience Chrome is relatively relaxed about file paths etc. Have you checked the CSS/JavaScript file path links are correct? I notice in the live preview all the paths are relative, try making them absolute. Also have you set `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">` in the header?

Comment: Thanks @Lyall . That solved my problem

Comment: Great - I'll add it as the answer, if you can please mark it as the accepted answer that would be great :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Compared to IE, in my experience Chrome is relatively relaxed about file paths etc. Have you checked the CSS/JavaScript file path links are correct? I notice in the live preview all the paths are relative, try making them absolute. Also have you set `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">` in the header?